# use theorrem 1.8.2 to show that T is a matrix transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[image]

I'm really lost on this one. is $2x + y$ and $x-y$ considered vectors? How do I do this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be confused between vector and components of vector.

In $\mathbb R^2$ every vector $v$ has two components each from $\mathbb R$,i.e say $v=(x,y)$ where components $x\in \mathbb R$ ,$y \in \mathbb R$

So if $u=(p,q),v=(r,s)$ then $u+v=(p+r,q+s)$ Thus we see $T(u)=(2p+q,p-q),T(v)=(2r+s,r-s)$,$T(u+v)=(2p+2r+q+s,p+r-q-s)\Rightarrow T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)$

and if $u=(p,q)$ then $ku=(kp,kq)$ So $T(ku)=(2kp+2kq,kp-kq)=k(2p+q,p-q)=kT(u)$

Answer (score 1):

In part (a), for example, by slight abuse of notation, we write $T(x,y)$ instead of $T(\mathbf{u})$ where $\mathbf{u}$ is a vector whose components are $\langle x, y\rangle$. So part (a) says that $T(\mathbf{u}) = \mathbf{v}$ where $\mathbf{u} = \langle x, y\rangle$ and $\mathbf{v} = \langle 2x+y, x-y\rangle$.